# Jquery AutoComplete Plugin calling

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

When I use JQuery's autocomplete and hardcode the array values in the page it works wonderful; but what I need to do is obtain the array values from either a web service or from a public function inside a controller. I have tried various way and can't seem to make it work. The farthest I got is pulling the data in to a long string and when the auto complete results are provided it's the long string which matches, which I understand why.

```
    $("#TaskEmailNotificationList").autocomplete("http://localhost/BetterTaskList/Accounts/registeredUsersEmailList", {
    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: false,
    multipleSeparator: ";",
    autoFill: true
  });
```

has anyone encountered this? I am using C#.

**UPDATE:**
The below code is a step forward I am now getting an array returned but I think I'm processing it wrong on my page.

```
  var emailList = "http://localhost/BetterTaskList/Account/RegisteredUsersEmailList";

  $("#TaskEmailNotificationList").autocomplete(emailList, {
    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: false,
    multipleSeparator: ";",
    autoFill: true
  });

 [HttpGet]
    public  ActionResult RegisteredUsersEmailList()
    {
       BetterTaskListDataContext db = new BetterTaskListDataContext();
        var emailList = from u in db.Users select u.LoweredUserName;
        return Json(emailList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your syntax looks different than I am used to.  If you are using the autocomplete widget that is part of jQuery UI, then the autocomplete syntax is like this:

```
$("#input1").autocomplete({
      source: "http://localhost/Whatever"
});
```

So maybe you are not using the autocomplete that is included in jQuery UI?

In case you are....
According to [the documentation for jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), the source can be one of three things; an array, a string (URL), or a function.   If it is an array, it can be objects or words. If objects, then each should expose either a `label`, or a `value` property or both.

If it is a URL, then it should return JSON that conforms to one of the array formats.  Eg, it should return

```
[ "albatross", "bison", "cayman", "duck", ...]
```

or

```
[ { "label": "albatross", "value": "72" }, 
  { "label": "bison", "value": "24" }, 
   ...
]
```

Most likely you are retrieving something that does not conform to one of the above formats.

See also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-autocomplete-plug-in-search-configuration/2405109#2405109)

Comment: I am using this autocomplete plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ which if I am not mistaken it's an extension of the jquery autocomplete feature. The question you refered me to shed some more light on my issue, now i have to figure out how to return a properly structured array. thanks.

Comment: Nope, you ARE mistaken.  The bassistance plugin is a different plugin, not an extension of the jQuery UI plugin.