# How can I make this link clickable in JQuery UI Autocomplete? Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, underscore.js

I'm trying to use the Jquery UI autocomplete plugin, and i'd like to render some html in the suggest box, with clickable links.  The html seems to render ok, however when I click the links, they don't work and I get in my developer log:

```
jquery-ui.min.js:239Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null
a.widget._create.menu.a.addClass.appendTo.mousedown.menu.selectedjquery-ui.min.js:239
a.Widget._triggerjquery-ui.min.js:23
a.widget.selectjquery-ui.min.js:252
a.widget._createjquery-ui.min.js:247
f.event.handlejquery.min.js:17
f.event.add.k.i.handle.k jquery.min.js:16
```

I'm using the following code in the HTML and Jquery side, the syntax is Haml as its in Rails.  In the first script tag, I just define a template that I then render with Underscore.js.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497076/add-a-link-to-a-jqueryui-autocomplete-item)  seems to reference a similar problem, but I don't understand the answer `"I think autocomplete uses an <a> for the element that provides the click event. In that case, you'll need to unset that click handler"`

I'd appreciate any guidance!  Its been 2 days I've been stuck on this.  Thanks!

[image: rendered autocomplete menu screenshot]

```
= text_field_tag :search, nil, :class => "jq_watermark", :id => "product-search-input", :title => "Keywords, Tags, Items, SKU..."

%script(type="text/html" id="product-autocomplete-result-template")
  .cell.img
    %img(src='{{ main_image_thumb }}')
  .cell
    %h2= link_to '{{ label }}', CGI::unescape(product_path('{{ id }}'))
    .clear
    = link_to '{{ customer_count }} people have this', '#'
    %span Rating {{ rating }}
    %div{:id => "stars-wrapper-{{ id }}"}
      %select= options_for_select([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    %a(href='http://www.google.com') 
      Click Me
  .cell 
    = link_to "I have this", '#', :class => "button"
    = link_to "I want this", '#', :class => "button"

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      var template = $('#product-autocomplete-result-template').html();
      var parsed_template = _.template(template, item);
      var target_option = 'value="' + item.rating + '"';    // do simple string replace to select option, as I can't get Jquery
      var selected_option = target_option + ' selected="selected"';
      var autocomplete_html = parsed_template.replace(target_option, selected_option);
      var returnVal = $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append('<a>' + autocomplete_html+'</a>')
        .appendTo( ul );
      $("#stars-wrapper-"+item.id).stars({ inputType: "select", disabled: true });
      return returnVal;
    };

    $('#product-search-input').autocomplete({
          delay: 50,
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "#{search_products_path}",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { term: request.term },
          success: function(data) {
            if (data.length < 1) {
              console.log("Juuusstt right");
              // show submit button
            } else {
              console.log("Too long");
              // hide submit button
            }
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      }
   })
  });
```

Comment: 'unset that click handler' means you return false in the select(). Your autocomplete() code looks right though, perhaps it's somewhere when it renders the autocomplete_html?

Comment: I think its related to the fact that jqueery autocomplete depends on jquery.ui.menu, and that file binds event handlers to the <a> elements in the auto complete list.  Prob is, it also binds them to the ones in my template... I think...

Comment: Is it possible that your search data is empty; thus when you render the menuitem via $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append('<a>' + autocomplete_html+'</a>').appendTo( ul ); The $( "<li></li>" ) is null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand..  by 'search data' you mean the autocomplete results from the server?  no its full..   I think the .data call through the error isn't the one in here, but in jquery.ui.menu.  When I comment out the data call in this file here, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find no evidence that this is doable without monkey patching a large part of jquery.  YUI3 works spectaculary well, however.  No monkeying around necessary

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/autocomplete/

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that you have already found a solution for it, but better late then never.

I know this isn´t the optimal solution, but it works.

```
$(".yourLink").live('click', function () {
    var yourLinkHref= $(this).attr('href');
    window.location = yourLinkHref;

});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, i left the project a while back, so I can't test this, but I ended up just going with YUI

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully it will help someone else with the same issue.