# Why is JQuery breaking my HTML, adding extra <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML code stored in a javascript string:  and I am using Jquery 1.6.1 from google CDN

console.log(string):

```
<a><div class='product-autocomplete-result'>
            <div class='cell img'>
              <img src='http://beta.prizzm.com.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product_image/image/1/thumb_serrano_navy_1.jpg'>
            </div>
            <div class='cell'>
              <h2><a href="/products/1">Serrano Hobo</a></h2>
              <div class='clear'></div>
              <a href="#">0 people have this</a>
              <span>Rating 3</span>
              <div id='stars-wrapper-1'>
                <select>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='cell'>
              <a href="#" class="button">I have this</a>
              <a href="#" class="button">I want this</a>
            </div>
          </div></a>
```

When I try to wrap this with JQuery, and output it, Jquery ends up closing my first `<a>` tag, and throwing other `<a>` tags in the code at seemingly random places, producing that in the screenshot here: (took screenshot because the output formatting was so bad)

[image]

The differences is that it
* closes the first `<a>` right away, 
* inserts second `<a>` surrounding my first `<div>`
* inserts third `<a>` after my second `<div>` before the `<h2>`
* inserts a 4th `<a>` after the `<h2>` and before the intended `<a>`

As a result this is really messing up the autocomplete code that I use afterwards.  This two snippets were literally generated one right after the other:

```
console.log(code);
console.log($(code));
```

Could someone please tell me whats going on an how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain what's going on, but it seems a little odd to be nesting anchor tags inside anchor tags - what is the expected behavior?

Comment: ah crap..  right..  ok..  I'm throwing the entire snippet inside of an jqeruy autocomplete output afterwards, and it needs <a> tags to make the item selectable. .. that's why I put them in

Comment: Just an fyi to everyone else responding: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: @noli: use spans and just set them to display block instead.

Comment: @prodigitalson..  wow..  put thatt answer here and i'lll credit you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577761/how-can-i-make-this-link-clickable-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete-uncaught-typeerror

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Block elements are not allowed inside `<a>` elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A) The browser tries to correct this but seems to produce invalid HTML code.

Make sure you have only *inline* elements inside.

Why do you have the outer `<a>` element anyway? It seems to serve no purpose. It does not even have an `href` attribute, which is invalid as well.

Just remove it.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to use this to render an autocomplete menu with jqueryui autocomplete.  And it seems that it needs to surround the autocomplete item with <a> tags in order to make it selectable.   Tracking it down, I think this is due to behavior in the jquery.ui.menu dependency.   Long story short, that's why they're there...  I didn't consider validation issues though

Comment: Details here for the curious  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577761/how-can-i-make-this-link-clickable-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete-uncaught-typeerror

Comment: @Noli:  Almost **anything** is already selectable with jQuery.  So you **do not** need `<a>` tags to make that happen.

Comment: @sparky I don't know what's going on really... maybe because i'm doing aspecial case with a feature that's not really well documented.  I'm monkey patching the _renderItem method on jquery.ui.autocomplete so that Ii can format the data how I want to.  However, if your HTML isn't surrounded by <a> tags, you can't select that item, as autocomplete depends on jquery.ui.menu, and it seems to bind the select event to <a> tags..  at least that's what it looks like looking through the code, and real life examples

Comment: @Noli:  Sounds like a whole different issue for a whole new question posting.  I've never seen `<a>` tags used like that I cannot imagine that jQueryUI would require such for the desired functionality.  I cannot speak to your specific project but I cannot imagine you being limited to only `<a>` tags for that plugin.  If that's truly the case then use a different jQuery auto-complete plugin... jQuery UI is not mandatory.

Comment: I can't imagine it either..  but it is what it is.  In other news..YUI 3 works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

`div`s are not valid within an `a` tag, use spans with `display:block;` instead, or change the a to a div and attach a click event handler to mimic an a tag.

Answer (score 3):

`div` is a block element. `a` is an inline element. Block elements are illegal inside of inline elements. I don't think it's really jQuery to blame so much as your browser fixing things up when jQuery sets an element's `innerHTML`.

Comment: Wrapping block elements in anchor tags is "legal" in html5.

Comment: Only if you declare the block elements as inline elements via CSS. It is not a recommended practice and has niche uses.

Comment: @kinakuta: Yes and no. The elements that are allowed in the `<a>` element are derived from the parent of that element. At least this is how I understand the *transparent* section: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#transparent . And besides that, HTML5 seems to categorize the elements totally differently...

Comment: Declaring the block elements as inline isn't required.

Comment: @Felix_King - the wording of the w3c spec leaves a lot to be desired - put more succinctly, what's specifically disallowed inside an anchor tag is any kind of interactive content: http://developers.whatwg.org/content-models.html#interactive-content

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place a block element `<div>` inside of an inline element `<a>`. Also, you cannot place another anchor tag within an anchor tag. There's all sorts of invalid code going on here, so jQuery is choking up on it.

I highly recommend you [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/), fix the errors, and go from there.

**Side Note:** HTML5 actually *does* allow block elements within inline elements, but only if you apply the proper CSS turning the block element into an inline element itself. Your best bet is to still stay away from block elements within inline for simplicity sake.