# jQueryUI autoComplete returns back empty list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In my asp.net mvc3 application, I added autoComplete for my search box.  When I test it, there are 3 results returned back from the action. You can see a list showed up, however, this is an empty list, you only see 3 < li >< /li >, and there's nothing there between the li tag.

I pretty sure, action is fine, because, It did return 3 results back.  I can verify that by seeing 3 empty < li > tag.  what should I do to add name  < li > apple < / li>

```
        $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
            source:"/Home/SearchIngredients",
            minLength: 2

        });


    public virtual JsonResult SearchIngredients(string term)
    {
        var ingredients = _smoothieService.GetIngredients(term);

        var data = ingredients.Select(x => new {Id = x.NDB_No, Value = x.Name}).Take(25).ToArray();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could it be a CSS problem? When you look in Firebug do you see the elements?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497076/add-a-link-to-a-jqueryui-autocomplete-item?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SearchIngredients",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {
                response(data.map(function (value) {
                    return {
                        'label': '<li>' + value.Id + '</li>',
                        'value': value.Value
                    };  
                }));
            }   
        }); 
    },  
    minLength: 2
})
```

Comment: Ah good catch, the `Value` property is uppercased. This would work but  he/she could also change the controller action to return a lowercase `value`

Comment: This saved me hours of searching the web for a solution. Thank You.