# mvc4 jquery autocomplete items showing up as asterisks instead of readable data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I got my autocomplete stuff working well enough to see that it's returning *some* data when I type in a field--but the data shown in the dropdown below the textbox is just a vertical column of asterisks or list item bullets. (I can't really tell what they are.)

When I query the web service directly in the browser, it returns a Json array as expected which looks like this where, for example ?term=chi (I've added some line breaks for readability)

```
[
 {"Name":"Chihuahua"},
 {"Name":"Chinese Crested"},
 {"Name":"Chinese Shar-Pei"},
 {"Name":"Japanese Chin"},
 {"Name":"Schipperke"}
```

]

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Breed").autocomplete({
        source: "@Url.Action("BreedList", "Patient")"
    });
});
```

like I say, my textbox in question (#Breed) does respond sort of like an autocomplete box, but the dropdown data is weird. Any ideas?

Comment: oh I wonder if it's some sort of missing CSS....?

Comment: I did add a style bundle to my shared _layout page that I think was missing: @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") which contains the autocomplete css, but now my autocomplete dropdown is just a thin sliver under the textbox and shows no data. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Although I did have a CSS bundling problem (somehow I had omitted the jquery ui css from my bundle), a bigger issue was that the Json returned by my service needed a lower case "value" property for each item. I was using the column name as cased on my Linq query. The tip that pointed me in the right direction on this came from the answer here: [jQueryUI autoComplete returns back empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393449/jqueryui-autocomplete-returns-back-empty-list)