# jQuery ui autocomplete with Django return 404

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui

I'm implementing an autocomplete search using jQuery UI and Django models.

Here is my `view`:

```
def get_ticker(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        symbols = Symbol.objects.filter(name__istartswith=q)
        results = []
        for symbol in symbols:
            symbol_json = {'name': symbol.name, 'symbol': symbol.symbol}
            results.append(symbol_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'Can\'t get data...'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

`url`:

```
url(r'^api/get_ticker/$', views.get_ticker, name='get_ticker'),
```

`js`:

```
$(function() {
   $("#ticker").autocomplete({
      source: "{% url get_ticker %}",
      minLength: 2,
   });
});
```

`html`:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
      <input type="text" id="ticker">
 </div>
```

When I type in search box, I get error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/finance/%7B%%20url%20get_ticker%20%%7D?term=hello 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Comment: Is the js served as static content or is it rendered? You need to render it (or put the url in the html file, which is probably a better idea).

Comment: it's is static content. How do rendered it?@noamk

Comment: There are ways to render static django content (you can find them using google), but that's not a good solution IMHO. This javascript file is served as-is, without changes. The proper way to do this is to put the url in some property in the html (which is rendered), and access the property from the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're serving the JS file separately. If that's the case, then you'll have to:

**either** write the full URL yourself in the JS file.

```
source: "/api/get_ticker/",
```

**or** copy the script in your HTML template.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("#ticker").autocomplete({
           source: "{% url 'get_ticker' %}",
           minLength: 2,
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think search is working but when I type in, it shows me drop down list without any text. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393449/jqueryui-autocomplete-returns-back-empty-list

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#ticker').autocomplete({
    source: "{% url 'get_ticker' %}",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting 404 (NOT FOUND).

Comment: Are your url and application registered?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 "{% url get_ticker %}"
```

with

```
 "{% url 'get_ticker' %}"
```

Make note of the quotes

Comment: I'm still getting 404 (NOT FOUND).

Comment: Yes exactly the same.@IanAuld

Comment: Try `"{% url 'get_ticker' | safe %}"`