# How do I limit results of jQuery autocomplete with categories?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I want to categorize jQuery autocomplete results [as in the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories), but I also want to limit the number of results in each category. I understand how to limit the number of *total* results using [an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071887/limit-the-result-in-jquery-autocomplete#answer-4072026) or [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete#answer-7617637), but I cannot figure out how to use them in combination with the categories functionality.

Say my data looks like this:

```
var data = [
  { label: "Location #1", category: "city" },
  { label: "Location #2", category: "city" },
  { label: "Location #3", category: "city" },
        // ...more locations \\
  { label: "Location #25", category: "city" },
  { label: "Person #1", category: "people" },
  { label: "Person #2", category: "people" },
  { label: "Person #3", category: "people" },
        // ...more people  \\
  { label: "Person #25", category: "people" }
];
```

If I limit the number of results to 5 using one of the above methods, this affects the *total* number of results, so if a user starts typing "o" in the search field, they will see:

***CITIES:***   *Location #1, Location #2, Location #3, Location #4, Location #5*

What I want to display, however, is a limit of 5 locations *and* 5 people:

***CITIES:***  *Location #1...Location #5*

...followed by:

***PEOPLE:***  *Person #1...Person #5*

My actual data is coming from a more complicated SQL query in CartoDB, but here is a simple JSFiddle that should suffice: http://jsfiddle.net/vqwBP/577/

Comment: i preffer  twitter typeahead with bloodhound

Comment: You're slicing the entire output list and only using the first 5 entries. You need to be slicing once per category.

Comment: Exactly, but I couldn't figure out how to slice twice, only once on the whole list (sorry, guess I didn't communicate that well). Got any links or tips on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript `Array.Filter` method can do what you need.  The predicate function `fn` must track a counter for each category, so it is wrapped inside a closure that maintains this state information.  The `counter` object must be extended to reflect all the possible categories exactly (case-sensitive).

```
var predicate = function () {
    var counter = { city: 0, people: 0, elves: 0 };
    var fn = function(item) {
        counter[item.category] += 1;
        return (counter[item.category] <= 5);
    }
    return fn;
}();

response(results.filter(predicate));
```

Try it at http://jsfiddle.net/Cfp2N/3/.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a ton. I cleaned some things up and here is the working result: http://jsfiddle.net/Cfp2N/4/