# Appending an item to a jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, append

Currently, I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete on a textbox that references an ASHX file.

Everything is working propertly, except I want to append an item at the end of the list that reads:  "Item not found?  Click here to request to add a new item."

I tried the following the lines of code, but all it did was format the item's, I was unable to append.

```
data( "catcomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.catcomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a class='ui-menu-item'></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
            .appendTo( $('ul').last('.autocomplete-category'));
    };
```

Hints?  Tips?  Mucho gracias! :D

Answer (score 9):

You should add your extra entry after the [`Open` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) fires. That will give you access to the list, which is what you are after, rather than to each element, which is what the `_renderItem` is giving you access to.

Here's an example styling the entries that have been populated into the list:

```
$("#myBox").autocomplete({
        source: "[URL]",
        minLength: 2,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $("ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:odd").css("background-color","#dedede");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mucho!  I'll play around with it.  So far, I did the following:

`open: function (event, ui) {
                    //$("ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:odd").css("background-color", "#dedede");
                    var url = "Can't find the item?  Request to add a <a href='javascript:void();' onclick='alert(\'TEST\');'>new</a> item!";
                    $("ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu").append(url);
                }`
It looks like I can append an item to the end of the list, now gotta make sure it's a clickable URL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to fiddle with `_renderItem`. That is the fn that renders one item; it is called once for each item in the list of suggestions.

What you want to do is monkeypatch the _renderMenu function. The original definition in jQuery UI 1.8.6 is like this:

```
_renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var self = this;
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        self._renderItem( ul, item );
    });
},
```

It's probably basically the same for other versions of jQuery UI.

Patch this to add your extra item, after doing the `$.each`.

Comment: This seems pretty brittle. If the UI team decided to update how the `_renderMenu` function worked, you would need to update your own code, since `_renderMenu` isn't part of the public API.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's why it's called *monkeypatching*. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results/2436493#2436493 for more details on the technique.