# JSON to array and search & replace inside the array

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, replace, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an small callback-function for an jQuery autocompleation input field.
The function has 2 parameters: term=the string, typed into the input field and url=the url to the php script which generates suggestions.

The script looked like that:

```
function m(term,url) {
   var y = '';
   jQuery.get(url, { term:term }, function(data){ });
   return y;
}
```

Everything you type into the text-field is send to the php script, which returns a list of suggestions.

Inside the `function(data){}` block, two things should be happened:

1. encode the JSON string into an Array (which is needed by the JQuery autocomplete as return value). I tried this: `y=eval("(" + data + ")");`. Is this right?
   The JSON string which is generates from the PHP side looks like that  (example for term="nur")

   ["nuri al maliki","nursultan nasarbajew","n\u00fcrnberger prozess"]
   n\u00fcrnberger is the encoded version of "nürnberger"
2. Highlight the term inside suggested word. Example: input value is "ris" so an suggestion example should be something like `sun<b>ris</b>e`.

Is there a way to use something like `.replace` for array?

The application run's under the Yii framework - so I would like to find an solution for that.

Comment: Don't know how to completely answer you question (having no experience with jQuery UI), but for your first question...don't use `eval`, use [`$.parseJSON(foo)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: @Zirak Interesting information, thank you!

Comment: You could also use `$.getJSON()`. Seems like the simplest way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the link from DarthJDG and followed to this SO question: [jQueryUI: how can I custom-format the Autocomplete plug-in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results)

I think because of insufficient knowledge in Javascript/Jquery/... I was unable to apply that solution to my application. All the time I got the error "$.ui is undefined".
The challenge (for me) was: where to place that code in combination with the Yii framework, which one I use.

So I got help from the Yii forum and I like to post the explicit solution here.

You simply have to register that following script. It's importent to register that at POS_LOAD:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('highlightAC','$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
            return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };',CClientScript::POS_LOAD);
```

That's it. 
(Thanks to Antonio from the Yii forum)

Answer (score 1):

its been said that eval is evil you don't need to parse the sting into json just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

please also look at [remote example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

for formatting see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results) provided by  @DarthJDG

Comment: +1 to RTFM, you can also have a look at the following SO question for custom formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results

Comment: i'm still using json_encode on PHP side. I use CJSON::encode from the yii framework.

Comment: @The Bndr maybe your json is incorrect ? here is another example that uses jsonp notice they don't need to parsjson http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp when it comes back

Comment: Not sure, but the JSON i receive from PHP side looks like that (example for term="nur") ["nuri al maliki","nursultan nasarbajew","n\u00fcrnberger prozess"]. I think that looks good.

Comment: @DarthJDG that SO link i also an interesting way. I'm very new in jQuery/JS. To implement that idea - i simply have to call the function monkyPatchAutocomplete? But i get the error, that "$.ui. is undefined" I think, that some basic knowledge is missing on my side. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can define that the string you receive comes in JSON by:

```
jQuery.get(url, { term:term }, function(data){ }, "json");
```

Then in the callback function go through the received items and replace your found string with the wrapped version:

```
for (i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    data[i] = data[i].replace(new RegExp(term), "<b>$1</b>");
}
```