# tagcompletion like stackoverflow

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/oquda3/2/)

**Bug**

- add an item that exists in the list
- add an item that doesn't exist in the list
- add an item that exists in the list by clicking arrow key or clicking an item with mouse
- notice that all items are erased and everything starts over.

I am building this on top of a solution provided to me in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162449/how-to-get-autocompletion-like-stack-overflow/6162549#6162549).  I've taken the code from that example and modified to my needs.  however, now I am having the issue stated above.

What can I do to avoid having the list erase all items when a new item is added by clicking down arrow key after a non existent item is added.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `options` object you pass the `autocomplete` widget:

```
focus: function() { return false; }
```

From the docs on `focus`:

> Canceling this event prevents the
>   value from being updated, but does not
>   prevent the menu item from being
>   focused.

Here's your example without the bug: http://jsbin.com/oquda3/4