# How to patch *just one* instance of Autocomplete on a page?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This answer --  [jQueryUI: how can I custom-format the Autocomplete plug-in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results/2436493#2436493)  -- describes how to monkeypatch the jqueryUI autocomplete widget, so that it displays things in a particular way. The approach it uses is to replace a function on the `$.ui.autocomplete.prototype`.

This means that *all* autocomplete widgets will get this patch.

Is there a way to patch the autocomplete widget for *just one input element*?
What is it?

When I examine `$('$input').autocomplete` , I don't see any of the autocomplete fns there (_renderItem, _renderMenu, _search, etc).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out the [custom data and display demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data). This demo is not modifying the prototype object of the autocomplete widget, meaning that only that instance of the widget is effected:

```
$("selector").autocomplete({ ... }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vJSwq/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in IE, the error is always is "`data(...)` is null or not an object." Is `data` actually unsupported in this case? Examples from http://api.jquery.com/data/ work properly, and the only warning on that page is that IE doesn't allow fiddling with XML in this way.

Comment: Try using `.data('uiAutocomplete')` instead. This was changed in recent versions of jQueryUI.

Comment: If you are getting a "Attempted to assign to readonly property." in webkit. Try using `.data('ui-autocomplete')`.

Comment: At this time, the last example on [this page](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/) suggests using `.data('ui-autocomplete')`.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker i am facing a problem when i hover the data the data disappear. i am using autocomplete jquery ui

Comment: @HassaanKhan: It would be best to open a new question

Answer (score 6):

The code from Andrew Whitaker just work for **one** autocomplete input. If you select more than one input-element, the second autocomplete widget dosn't show any entrys. 
You have to add a *foreach* to handel all selected input elements like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410962/jquery-autocomplete-for-2-input-field-same-class?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
$("selector")
.autocomplete({ ... })
.each(function () {
    $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
);
```

Comment: I just ran into this today, with multiple instances. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For recent versions of jQuery(1.8+) / jQuery UI (1.10+), you should use:

```
$("selector").autocomplete({ ... }).data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```