# monkey patching one jquery ui autocomplete render item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, monkeypatching

```
$("selector").autocomplete({ ... }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164621/106261)

What is this bit doing `.data( "autocomplete" )` I though data was used to attach key value pairs to dom elements as part of `data-foo` attribute. But that doesn't seem the case here ?

Comment: Do any one have an idea how to append the above entire return to span which is also created in the widget...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) :

- `.data(name, value)` is the setter : it attaches `value` to the `name` key
- `.data(name)` is the getter : it returns the value attached to the `name` key

In this case, the value is an object (which stores data about the autocomplete instance bound to the node), and this object is modified in place.

It is a common pattern in the jQuery library to have a function trigger different actions depending on its arguments :

- `$(selector).click(myFunction)` binds a handler to the nodes, `$(selector).click()` triggers the `click` event
- in jquery-ui, `$sel.widget('option', name, value)` will generally allow you to change an option after a widget has been created, `$sel.widget('option', name )` will allow you to get the value
- etc ...

Comment: ah of course, so it returns the autocomplete function, then changes the renderItem property of autocomplete to the function supplied... ?

Comment: yes : on its creation, the automcomplete widget creates a configuration object, and stores it with the node using the `.data()` function. You can then access it with the `autocomplete` key.