# Jquery autocomplete with multiple keywords, highlighting and partial matches

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm on the hunt for a JQuery autocomplete that will:

- Search partial matches
- Highlight all occurrences whereever they appear
- Allow multiple word
- Allow remote datasources (i.e. PHP filters database results based on querystring that dynamically updates with each keypress)

So for example

Search:
"me wa home"

Returns:
"show **me** the **wa** y to go **home**"

I'm having a terrible time trying to find something that can offer this, even though it is common expectation of a Google-style autocomplete.

The monkeypatch of jquery ui autocomplete ( [jQueryUI: how can I custom-format the Autocomplete plug-in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results) ) comes close, but doesn't seem to offer dynamic remote datasources.

I've also come close with the following script:

```
var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
$("#f input").autocomplete({
   source: "livesearch.php",
   open: function(e, ui) {
      var origKeyword = $("#f input").val();
      var acData = $(this).data('autocomplete');
      acData.menu.element.find('a').each(function() {
         var me = $(this);
         var regex = new RegExp(acData.term, "gi");
         me.html(me.text().replace(regex, function(matched) {
            return termTemplate.replace('%s', matched);
         }));
      });

   },
   select: function(event, ui) {
      var keyword = $("#f input").val();
      $("#f input").val('');
      window.location.href = 'MYURLHERE?VARIABLE=' + ui.item.value;
      return false;
   },
   focus: function(event, ui) {
      return false;
   }
});
```

However, it doesn't handle highlighting multiple words separated by a space.

if anyone has any suggestions, I'd be hugely grateful.

Comment: Use a function for the source option to manually query the server.  Look at step 4 here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/ Note in step 5 that autocomplete passes the search items to `$_GET['term']`

Comment: Yes, a dynamic remote source is definitely possible. Highlighting the individual words is harder, but not impossible with jQueryUI autocomplete

Comment: Thanks Nal.  I've had a go at adding in the function you mentioned into code the supports multiple highlighting.  However I can't get it working.  Would you might having a look at my code in Answer 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I went with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'>
   .srchHilite {background-color: yellow;}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
$("#tags").autocomplete({
 source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("livesearch.php", request, function(data, status, xhr ) {

            var newmatchArry = new Array();
            var matchArry   = data.slice ();
            var srchTerms   = $.trim (request.term).split (/\s+/);

                //--- For each search term, remove non-matches.
                $.each (srchTerms, function (J, term) {
                    var regX    = new RegExp (term.value, "i");
                    matchArry   = $.map (matchArry, function (item) {
                        return regX.test (item)  ?  item  : null;
                    } );
                } );

            response(matchArry);

        });
    },

  open:   function (event, ui) {
                /*--- This function provides no hooks to the results list, so we have to trust the
                    selector, for now.
                */
                var resultsList = $("ul.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-menu-item > a");
                var srchTerm    = $.trim ( $("#tags").val () ).split (/\s+/).join ('|');

                //--- Loop through the results list and highlight the terms.
                resultsList.each ( function () {
                    var jThis   = $(this);
                    var regX    = new RegExp ('(' + srchTerm + ')', "ig");
                    var oldTxt  = jThis.text ();

                    jThis.html (oldTxt.replace (regX, '<span class="srchHilite">$1</span>') );
                } );
            }
} );

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="tags">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@user287212, I did some research about JQuery AutoComplete with multiple keywords. I found an example in this [address](http://demo.componentone.com/wijmo/InvExplorer/). It's a complex example but there is a JQuery AutoComplete example with multiple keywords. If you write a symbol in the symbol input, the program will bring to you the terms in the file. Example explanation at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424656/A-Stock-Portfolio-Application-Using-KnockoutJS). You can look on this link.

Comment: Thanks Aziz.  That certainly seems to do what I want... but it's technically out of my league I think.  I'll certainly have a look at it though.  I was just hoping I'd be able to modify my example above as it's sooo close to working.