# jQuery Autocomplete - how to make matching text bold

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery's autocomplete to display suggestions to the user for a text input field and I'm having a hard time making the matching text in the suggestion list bold. For example, if a user starts to type in "balt", the text "balt" in each of the autocomplete suggestions displayed should be bolded like this:

"**Balt**imore, USA - **Balt**imore Intl. (BWI)"

(similar to what Kayak.com does on their search form).

JS:

```
var airportList = [
{"IATA":"BWI","city":"Baltimore","airp":"Baltimore Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"SEA","city":"Seattle","airp":"Seattle Tacoma Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"LAX","city":"Los Angeles","airp":"Los Angeles Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"JFK","city":"New York","airp":"John F. Kennedy Intl.","country":"USA"}];

$("#input1").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response){

    var searchTerm = request.term.toLowerCase();
    var ret = [];
    var ph;
    $.each(airportList, function(i, airport){
        if (airport.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airport.IATA.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 || airport.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airport.airp.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0) {
        ph = airport.city + ', ' + airport.country + ' - ' + airport.airp + ' (' + airport.IATA + ')';

        // ph is each suggestion that will appear in the suggestions list, i need to 
        // make the substring in ph that matches the searchTerm appear bold; I've tried
        // replacing the substring with the same substring with <strong> tags around it
        // and the .bold() function, neither worked.

        ret.push(ph);
        }

        });

        response(ret);
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ray9209/v9o71L11/2/

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Here, look at this: http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Comment: var ph is a string, not a jquery object so the highlight plugin won't work.

Comment: Why would you put html in your json object, when you can render the jquery object (selector) as you display it

Comment: @AmitJoki: here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ray9209/v9o71L11/1/ if it helps (the autocomplete suggestions actually aren't working for some reason, they're working on my server).

Comment: You need to add jQuery UI to your external resources or your fiddle won't work

Comment: Thanks @ZeeTee, fiddle works now: http://jsfiddle.net/ray9209/v9o71L11/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I custom-format the Autocomplete plug-in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you should use the _renderItem function, which basically renders the items in the result list. In this function you would replace the searched string with a new string surrounded by  tag.

```
var airportList = [
{"IATA":"BWI","city":"Baltimore","airp":"Baltimore Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"SEA","city":"Seattle","airp":"Seattle Tacoma Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"LAX","city":"Los Angeles","airp":"Los Angeles Intl.","country":"USA"},
{"IATA":"JFK","city":"New York","airp":"John F. Kennedy Intl.","country":"USA"}];

$("#input1").autocomplete({
minLength: 3,
source: function(request, response){

var searchTerm = request.term.toLowerCase();
var ret = [];
var ph;
$.each(airportList, function(i, airport){
    if (airport.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 ||   airport.IATA.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 || airport.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0 || airport.airp.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0) {
    ph = airport.city + ', ' + airport.country + ' - ' + airport.airp + ' (' + airport.IATA + ')';

    // ph is each suggestion that will appear in the suggestions list, i need to 
    // make the substring in ph that matches the searchTerm appear bold; I've tried
    // replacing the substring with the same substring with <strong> tags around it
    // and the .bold() function, neither worked.

    ret.push(ph);
    }

    });

    response(ret);
}
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .attr( "data-value", item.value )
    .append( $( "<a>" ).html( item.label.replace(new RegExp(this.term, 'gi'),"<b>$&</b>") ) )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is you're initializing your autocomplete with a static source and expecting to show different data each time you search.

Instead, put your highlighting process in the [`response()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event to capture the returned data after each search before it renders, like so:

```
,response: function( event, ui ) {
   //render through the ui object here to update the highlighting on the results.
   if(ui.length>0){
     ui[0].label = "highlighted text";
   }
}
```