# JQuery UI autocomplete + tag plugin (XOXCO) : tag is not added upon selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-tags-input

My problem is when using `Jquery UI autocomplete` and `tag plugin (XOXCO)` together, once I `select` one of the autocomplete suggestions it should add the tag right away, but what happens is that upon the selection, the suggestions disappear and though the `value` is written to the `tags-id` input correctly still the `label` itself does not show as a tag unless I press `enter`, if I don't then the tag won't be added correctly.

I think I should tell the tag plugin to go ahead and create the tag once I trigger the select event from the autocomplete plugin.. but I'm not able to get it done.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Search Locations</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" />

    <style>body {   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    table {font-size: 1em;}
    .ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {background-position: top;}
    .ui-autocomplete { line-height:24px; }
    .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-state-active.ui-button:hover 
    { border: 1px solid #000; background: #000; }
    .ui-menu-item { margin: 0; padding: 0; zoom: 1; float: left; clear: left; width: 100%; }
    .ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item { padding: 1px; width:350px; }
    .ui-menu-item a { text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: .2em .4em; line-height: 1.5; zoom: 1; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#tags" ).tagsInput({ 
    width: 'auto',
    interactive:true,
   defaultText:'add a piece of data',
    });
    $( "#tags_tag" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "xxxtestjsondata77.asp",
                        data: {term:request.term}, 
                        type: 'GET', 
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        } // close success
                    }); // close ajax
                }, // close source,

    select: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#tags_tag" ).val( ui.item.label );
                  $( "#tags-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                  return false;
               },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#tags_tag" ).val( ui.item.label );
                  return false;
               }

    });
    $( "#tags_tag" ).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

        var term = this.element.val(),
            regex = new RegExp( '(' + term + ')', 'gi' );
        t = item.label.replace( regex , "<b>$&</b>" );
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + t + " | " + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo( ul );

       }; 

  } ); // close document


  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Add Data</h1>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags" type="text">Tags: </label>
    <input name="tags" id="tags" />
    <input type="hidden" id="tags-id">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

part of the JSON File Data (xxxtestjsondata77.asp):

```
[ 
{ "label": "Data 1", "desc":"Data 1 desc", "value":"111" } , 
{ "label": "Data 2", "desc":"Data 1 desc", "value":"222" } , 
{ "label": "Data 3", "desc":"Data 1 desc", "value":"333" } } 
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why are you wrapping the rendered itemwith `<a>`? I would expect it to be wrapped with `<div>`.

Comment: @Twisty .. Thnx.. actually for no specific reason, I just used some of the help of the `autocomplete monkey-patching` in the answer of *@cheeso* here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436493/9811575) and the `_renderItem` variable was wrapped in an `anchor` not a `div`.

Comment: @Twisty.. actually the `Jquery UI autocomplete` is working fine on its own and the `tag plugin` is working fine on its own .. but when I used them together, I needed the `tag plugin` to do something different which is to add the tag when the user selects a suggestion from the autocomplete not upon  pressing the `enter` key ..  but I'm not able to get it done.

Comment: I am not familiar with this tag plugin. Since you advise that it works when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit, I suspect that this is triggering `change` or `submit` event. Since you're populating the field programmaticly, `change` is not executed. Maybe add  `$("#tags-id").trigger("change");`

Comment: ah~ I finally did it.. I was thinking upside down.. I was trying to manipulate the `tag plugin` to add the tag but the answer was in the `autocomplete plugin` in the `select` function I added `$('#tags').addTag(ui.item.label);` instead of `$( "#tags_tag" ).val( ui.item.label );` .. tada~ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and I'm adding it here for anyone who would want to know it.

Within the `autocomplete plugin` in the `select` function I added `$('#tags').addTag(ui.item.label);` instead of `$( "#tags_tag" ).val( ui.item.label );` like this:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
                  $('#tags').addTag(ui.item.label);
                  $( "#tags-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                  return false;
               },
```

and it worked like a charm.