# Can auto-complete of JQuery search words that starts from the typed letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I try to use [Jquery auto-complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I have managed to do that but, if I type "a", auto-complete suggest all words that contain "a". But I want to see only those words that starts from "a". Is it possible to force the auto-complete to behave the way I want?

Comment: Are you using a remote data source?

Comment: @polarblau, I am not sure that I understand you... The data (set of words and phrases that are used for auto complete) is loaded to the client side once (when the page is loaded).

Comment: Okay, then you're using a local data source and can't handle this with a server side scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

The brute-force way would be via a callback. That allows you to do the word matching yourself.

Comment: By callback, do you mean hooking the `Search` event?

Comment: $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

Answer (score 0):

This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148195/jquery-ui-autocomplete-use-startswith) earlier, it seems.