# Prefix Matching for Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to do a prefix matching for my autocomplete based on Jquery UI. I could not figure out a way so decided to dig into the code in `jquery-ui-autocomplete.js`. I'm not able to figure out where to do this matching in the code. Can anyone help me out ? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148195/jquery-ui-autocomplete-use-startswith

Comment: I got it working with a simple tweak in the jquery ui code. The link  posted above helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have blog post with example autocomplete with jquery: http://blog.goranobradovic.com/2011/07/autocompleting-cascading-dropdowns/

It may be of use to you, and simpler/easier than digging through autocomplete source.

Sorry for the images in the post, but you have link to complete source available.