# Auto Complete functionality: How to load text which is related to starting letter

Tags: jquery

I am using autocomplete functionality for my form. i have used below jquery script to implement the autocomplete function.

```
<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>
```

The o/p which comes through above code is its fetching all the words related to the letter which we are entering in the input box.
For example: If i am typing "C" then its fetching all the words which contains C. But i would like to have the words starting with C alone.

HTML Part is:

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
```

Please any one help on this....Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148195/jquery-ui-autocomplete-use-startswith

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Autocomplete widget search configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-search-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

HTML Part :

```
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags" />
```

Replace to:

```
<label for="autocomplete">Tags: </label>
  <input id="autocomplete" />
```

And Js Part

```
 <script>
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
 });
</script>
```

Replace to :

```
<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
      var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
      response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
          return matcher.test( item );
      }) );
  }
 });
```

It will work

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8HwfJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try to below code:

```
<title>Autocomplete</title>
<body>
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var availableTags = [
 "ActionScript",
 "AppleScript",
 "Asp",
 "BASIC",
 "C",
 "C++",
 "Clojure",
 "COBOL",
 "ColdFusion",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Groovy",
 "Haskell",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala",
 "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    var matches = $.map( availableTags, function(tag) {
      if ( tag.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
       return tag;
     }
    });
   response(matches);
 }
});
```

I have `copied` this script from jQuery forum.

Below is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w44jB/) for same.