# how to create autocomplete for checking the given letters in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to use autocomplete function in my jsp page, but it display items is not perfect match given letter.

now i am display state using auto complete,

i had jquery as,

```
states.push(stateslist);
$( "#state" ).autocomplete({
source: states
});
```

html code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="state">states: </label>
<input id="state">
</div>
```

but the textbox display not correct manner that like as,[image]

Comment: in given example you want states that starts with "ta"?

Comment: are you saying you only want the items to appear if they match the left side of the string instead of any part of the string? if so, this thread will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148195/jquery-ui-autocomplete-use-startswith