# Autocomplete UI, highlight multiple words in tags

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Highlighting multiple words work fine without tags in source but I'm looking for a way to do it with tags.

For example if the search is "jo ramo" the results should be "**Jo**ey **Ramo**nes".

```
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [
            { "label": "<span class=\"item1\">Joey</span> <span class=\"item2\">Ramones</span>"},
            { "label": "<span class=\"item1\">Johnny</span> <span class=\"item2\">Ramones</span>"},
            { "label": "<span class=\"item1\">Dee Dee</span> <span class=\"item2\">Ramones</span>"}            
        ],
        minLength: 2
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        var searchMask = this.element.val();
        var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");
        var replaceMask = "<b>$&</b>";
        var html = item.label.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append($('<div class="item"></div>').html(html))
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

[**Here is a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeromeM/m5Lpthbe/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053987/4891892) we can override the autocomplete filter methods to create our custom filters.

```
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    term=term.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '[^]*');// to search multiple words    
    var matcher = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
        return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
```

To match a "jo ramo" pattern to "**Jo**ey **Ramo**nes" i used `[^]*` in RegExp

Matched elements are pushed to `_renderItem` function, modified the function as per required ui(to highlight multiple words)

```
function(ul, item) {
    var searchMask = this.element.val().trim();
    var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");
    var replaceMask = "<b>$&</b>";
    var html=$(item.label).text(); // manipulating text only
    var splitText = searchMask.split(' ');

    $.each( splitText, function( index, value ){
        html = html.replace(new RegExp(value, "ig"), replaceMask);
    });        

    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append($('<div class="item"></div>').html(html))
        .appendTo(ul);
}
```

example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqQzw