# Ui-autocomplete not showing the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an autcomplete of my site.
When you start typing the entire box shows. 
Is there an option we can add, that only the options that have to do with the letters i typed should show up?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to a few other SO questions. Rather than copy their answers to here, you can check these links out and see if the accepted answers will assist you in your case.

[jQuery UI Autocomplete widget search configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-search-configuration)

[jQuery UI Autocomplete use startsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148195/jquery-ui-autocomplete-use-startswith)