# Autocomplete JQuery shows all the results without filtering them

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jQuery [`autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) code show all options, regardless of what is typed in the input field. How are the displayed options limited to items based on what it typed?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#inputfield").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var data = $.map(resultUsers, function(value, key) {
        return {
          label: value.name + " - " + value.city,
          value: value.name
        }
      });
      response(data);
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="inputfield">
```

Comment: What is `resultUsers` supposed to be? Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question here.

Comment: Seems to work fine when provided something like `const resultUsers = [{"name": "one", "city": "hey"},{"name": "two", "city": "ya"}];`. How and where are you trying to filter that?

Comment: @CBroe
This is an example of resultUsers:

var resultUsers = [{"name":"Mario","surname":"Rossi","city":"Rieti"},{"name":"Luca","surname":"Verdi","city":"Rome"};

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles All results present in resultUsers are shown, as if the autocomplete did not work

Comment: _"as if the autocomplete did not work"_ - more like, as if you forgot to actually do _your_ part in this :-) https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source clearly explains it: _"A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: **the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term**"_ - filtering the data according to the user input is _your_ responsibility, when you use a callback function as `source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `function(request, response) { ... } response(data);` "wrapper", and
2. Add filter overwrite.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#inputfield").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: $.map(resultUsers, function(value, key) {
      return {
        label: value.name + " - " + value.city,
        value: value.name
      }
    })
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});

const resultUsers = [
  {"name": "one", "city": "hey"}, {"name": "two", "city": "ya"}
];

// CREDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053987/2743458
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function(array, term) {
  var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
  return $.grep(array, function(value) {
    return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="inputfield">
```

Including the [ui filter overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053987/2743458) is only necessary to restrict limiting the results to items start with what is typed.

Credit for "starts with" filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053987/2743458

---

Looking at @cbroe 's final comment on the question—when a callback is assigned to the `source` property the `response()` function displays the suggested options after filtering.

So the source callback also needs to filter the potential options, and reformat them into the `label`/`value` return object. jQuery `map()` function can do both:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#inputfield").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (req, res) {
      let data = $.map(resultUsers, function(value, key) {
      
        // FILTER to include options that start with search term
        if ( 0 === value.name.indexOf(req.term) ) {
        
          // MAP to label/value object
          return { // <-- reformat
            label: value.name + " - " + value.city,
            value: value.name
          }
        } else { return null; }
      });
      res(data);
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});

const resultUsers = [
  {"name": "one", "city": "hey"}, {"name": "two", "city": "ya"}
];
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="inputfield">
```

No need to modify the `$.ui.autocomplete.filter()` function, as in the solution above.

Comment: Thank you, this tip was really helpful to me in solving my problem, i m sorry for not being complete and accurate in my question but I am a new user on stackoverflow