# php mysql jquery AJAX smart autocomplete solution

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I have a mysql table with a column containing a list of names.

Can anybody tell me the best plugin or solution for making an autosuggestion list in my form input field using jquery?

I need something which supports

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%$_POST[]"name"%' ";
```

limiting to 10

I need a package including js libraries and php files.

I need the smartest and powerful autocomplete solution which check for matches in my every key stroke, available today.

Thanks in advance.

blasteralfred

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-autocomplete-plug-in-search-configuration/2405109#2405109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI auto complete, you will need the do the server side interaction code though.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/