# JQuery Autocomplete UI Search At Beginning

Tags: jquery, search, user-interface, autocomplete

Using JQuery AutoComplete UI ,1.8, I need to change the search so it matches only at the start of the string.
Background my source comes from an ajax call that I don't control that returns 15,000 and their corresponding PKs. value is the name and Id is the integer PK.The code below works but since I'm searching through 15,00 strings that matches any where in the string it is too slow.
I've seen this post, link, but I couldn't figure out how to do without losing the Id field in the source.

I need the search to only match the beginning of value in data.d without losing the Id field.
This is an ASP.Net app but I don't think it matters.
Ideas?

```
$("#companyList").autocomplete({
              minLength: 4,
              source: data.d,
              focus: function(event, ui) {
                  $('#companyList').val(ui.item.value);
                  return false;
              },
              select: function(event, ui) {
                  $('#companyList').val(ui.item.value);
                  $('#<%= hdnCompanyListSelectedValue.ClientID %>').val(ui.item.Id);
                  return false;
              }
          });
```

Comment: link that disappeared, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2382497/714105

Comment: You're right - It doesn't matter that it's an ASPNET app. What do you mean by *I couldn't figure out how to do without losing the Id field in the source*? The source can be a function; you need to replace your source with a fn, which scans through the `data.d` and finds what you want, then invokes the `responseFn` with the result set. Eg, instead of `source: data.d,`  you need to supply `source: function(req,responseFn){...}`  It's not clear what problem you're having with "losing the id".

Comment: Maybe what you mean is, you want the id to be available in the `select:` fn when it gets invoked, is that right? In that case you may also want to patch the `_renderMenu` and `_renderItem` fns, to insert the id into the `<li>` element for each value - maybe use a custom attribute. For how to do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results/2436493#2436493

Comment: if i change source this this below 1) it doesn't work 2) the only way I could make it work was to only pass in the names which meant I wouldn't have the Id in the select.  source: function(req, responseFn) {
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
                            var a = $.grep( data.d, function(item,index){
                                return matcher.test(item);
                            });
                            responseFn( a );
                        }

Comment: @Cheeso, correct on your 2nd comment, I need the Id for the select

Comment: I was also looking at the search event but I couldn't tell which methods applied to ui, so I can't tell what's in there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you. You guys were on the right track. I used a json string as the datasource and I know the text I want to match is in the item.label field. It might be in item.value for you:
Input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="state" name="state" /> 
<input
readonly="readonly" type="text" id="abbrev" name="abbrev" maxlength="2"
size="2"/>
<input type="hidden" id="state_id" name="state_id" />
```

jQuery

```
var states = [{"id":"1","label":"Armed Forces Americas (except Canada)","abbrev":"AA"},{"id":"2","label":"Armed Forces Africa, Canada, Europe, Middle East","abbrev":"AE"},{"id":"5","label":"Armed Forces Pacific","abbrev":"AP"},{"id":"9","label":"California","abbrev":"CA"},{"id":"10","label":"Colorado","abbrev":"CO"},{"id":"14","label":"Florida","abbrev":"FL"},{"id":"16","label":"Georgia","abbrev":"GA"},{"id":"33","label":"Northern Mariana Islands","abbrev":"MP"},{"id":"36","label":"North Carolina","abbrev":"NC"},{"id":"37","label":"North Dakota","abbrev":"ND"},{"id":"43","label":"New York","abbrev":"NY"},{"id":"46","label":"Oregon","abbrev":"OR"}];

$("#state").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) { 
    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term); 
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" ); 
    response($.grep( states, function(item){ 
        return matcher.test(item.label); }) ); 
     },
minLength: 2,
select: function(event, ui) {
$('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
$('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
}
});
```

And here is a working example:
http://www.jensbits.com/demos/autocomplete/index3.php

Comment: nice!!! This solution also works with a plain array ["one", "two", "three"] . You only have to remove the '.label' from matcher.test(item.label)