# jQuery UI Autocomplete - search from the beginning of the string

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to set Jquery UI plugin to search only from the beginning of the string. I find some simillar questions but no usable answer. 
I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{!$basePath}/mesta.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var data = $( "city", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $( "name", this ).text(),
                    id: $( "name", this ).text()
                };
            }).get();
            $( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 0
            });
        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-autocomplete-plug-in-search-configuration

Comment: Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791379/jquery-autocomplete-ui-search-at-beginning

Comment: I know these topics but I don't know ho to aplicate it to my code.

Comment: I dont know how to implement it. Because I read the data from an XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply what is in the link @Samich posted to your `source` option:

```
source: function(req, response) { 
    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term); 
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" ); 
    response($.grep( data, function(item){ 
        return matcher.test(item.value); }) ); 
 },
```

And here is a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/PekQZ/