# Jquery autocomplete wildcard

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using the `jquery.ui.autocomplete` plugin, but I noticed when it searches, it uses a wild-card like this `'%value%'`.

I am using the auto-complete for zip-codes, and I think it would make more sense of the wild-card worked like this `'value%'` so when you start typing it only filters out the items that 'start with' what you already typed.

I can't find any documentation on this though.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function as the source option for the autocomplete plugin which should allow you to get the behaviour you want.

There's a very similar question asked here: [jQuery UI Autocomplete widget search configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-autocomplete-plug-in-search-configuration) which has an excellent answer and working example.