# how to show only typed string in textbox autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I have a autocomplete textbox. When am typing, the suggested list will shows. My code is given below,

```
$('#state').keyup(function(){
    $('#state_sugg').slideDown('fast');
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
    $('#state_sugg span').hide();
    var trs = $('#state_sugg span').filter(function(d){
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1;
    });
    trs.show();   
});
```

The above code is working fine.

Now the result is, when am typing `i` if any string having letter `i` will be displayed. ie, if am typing `i` the result will be `pondicherry, tamil nadu` etc.

But i want the result as, if am typing `ke` the result should be `kerala`. ie, the string starts with the letter am typing should be displayed.

For that how to edit the above code. I have tried a lot.

Comment: where is the code through which names are coming?

Comment: you should change your php code to query by StartsWith rather than contains criteria.

Comment: @Anant Actually the names coming from database.

Comment: @Robert : In the above code how to edit?

Comment: so in the query change `where state_name like `ke%`(check like manual)`

Comment: try with  `return $(this).text().toLowerCase().startsWith(val);`

Comment: use `lookupFilter ` like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239664/jquery-autocomplete-filter-match-by-first-letter

Comment: @ranjan you saved my time. It's working. Thanks.

Comment: @JithinVarghese glad to help :)