# jQuery UI Autocomplete Partial Match

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to make the jQuery UI Autocomplete search only the first few letters of my strings.  I thought I could do a key/ value thing with jQuery UI, but I am not sure if that applies.

I have the following string:

```
AGREE Agreement by and between BLANK, in BLANK, of the county records.
```

Only `AGREE` should be searched, not the rest of the string.  `AGREE` is the text-code that the user will search for.

Here is my simple code:

```
var availableTags = [
            "AGREE Agreement by and between BLANK, in BLANK, of the county records.",
            "CONDO Covenants, conditions, restrictions, reservations, terms, provisions, easements, liens for assessments, options, powers of attorney and limitations on title as set forth in the Ohio Revised Code Chapter 5311, or as set forth in the Declaration of Condominium ownership and Bylaws as recorded in BLANK, as amended, plat BLANK, of the county records."
        ];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableTags
});
```

Only the first words `AGREE` and `CONDO` should be searched, not the rest of the strings.  Is this possible/ feasible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Autocomplete widget search configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-search-configuration). Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2405109/303270) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>autocomplete demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">
<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref.  http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search  (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only searching for the tags then why don't you just put the tags in the array?

Comment: True, but I need the rest of the text to autopopulate in the textbox.

Comment: My advice would be to add the text using jQuery `append()` after the keyword is selected.

Comment: What do you think about the bottom of this page http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search where it says, "**Demo: Example: Using a custom source callback to match only the beginning of terms**"  Do you think I could use that?  It sounds like what I want to do...

Comment: Could work. Or you can use a `keyup` event and check with an if statement for a specific value or values in that text box and `append()` additional text based in that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It was very helpful, but I think I will go with the method on that page I linked to above.  I posted my solution below.

Comment: Just glad you got it figured out.  Mark your own solution as the answer ok.