# Autocomplete pop-up for 41.000 entries in Javascript/Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, popup

I have tried to use a JQuery autocomplete pop-up with 41.000 entries to select one of these. It works but it is far too slow from a user perspective.

Is there any open source library offering an autocomplete capable of supporting that many entries? Or is there any other similar design/feature I could use to have an autocomplete on 41.000 entries? What would be the alternatives if no solution is available?

Comment: Maybe you can use the minLength option to reduce the number of records displayed ?

Comment: Don't dump your database on the client, with socket.io and redis you can do autocomplete so fast it doesn't even feel like there the data is coming over wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution. I have implemented [my own source function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-search-configuration). It limits the number of returned entries to 12 and works smoothly with my 41.000 input entries.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with autocomplete it is with data, so the solution should be you can index or cache your results. There are many indexing mechanism available, I used Lucene indexing to perform my task with such heavy data.

Comment: The data is available at the user side. I don't need to fetch it from the server.

Comment: You could use AJAX to fetch the array instead of putting it into the HTML, increase the delay and the required minLength before querying the server in order to reduce the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax, like Google.

Comment: The data is available at the user side. I don't need to fetch it from the server.

Comment: I suppose it's available at user side because you have previously fetched it, or is it statically written in your HTML?  Perhaps it's too  much data for JS, so you should try a selective fetching by Ajax.